# Getting Intermittent 404 Not Found error in google Bigquery API

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Python 2.X to insert into Bigquery table from file

The method that i am using is `load_table_from_file()`

From today i started to recieve  404 with not much details

Here is the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 PUT
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project/jobs?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2UodF7My9IjTefRjWHDSIKZeBxDdjRhSmO9-DJH5l7md4Nt-4ZnpJ5n0u9H0MgEUWYATVfVORWywlgErRhWCuWvgB9PBFg:
Not Found`
```

Could someone guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with the google bigquery service itself!